# Fetching and displaying facebook profile picture in a UIImage

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm trying to make a facebook friend picker displaying the friends who currently have the app installed that are also facebook friends with the current user.

Here I'm fetching the user's facebook profile picture but, I seem to have a warning where the last statement is not used. Thanks for your help.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"friendCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    PFUser *facebookID = [[PFUser alloc] init];
    facebookID = [friendUsers objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fbIdString = [[NSString alloc] init];
    fbIdString = [facebookID objectForKey:@"fbId"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        NSURL *profilePictureURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", fbIdString]];
        NSData *picData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:profilePictureURL];
        UIImage *fbPic = (UIImage *)[self.view viewWithTag:1001];
        [fbPic initWithData:picData];

    }



    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Is the image not showing, are you getting a warning that you don't want to have? If the latter, what's the warning?

Comment: Well at the moment, it's not fetching the profile picture, because I haven't initialized the picture with picData, but I'm getting a warning on that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually assign the result of the `initWithData:` call to your `fbPic` image.
E.g.

```
fbPic = [fbPic initWithData: picData];
```

From the [apple documentation on UIImage](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

`- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data`

**Parameters**

- data -
  The data object containing the image data.

**Return Value**

- An initialized UIImage object, or nil if the method could not initialize the image from the specified data.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1. `UIImage *fbPic = (UIImage *)[self.view viewWithTag:1001];` - I think you're trying to get the UIImageView from the cell?
2. There's no UIImageView where you're actually showing the image.

It should be something like this:

```
if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        NSURL *profilePictureURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", fbIdString]];
        NSData *picData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:profilePictureURL];
        UIImageView *fbPicImageView = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:1001];
        [fbPicImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:picData]];
    }
```